# Troubleshooting "Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains"

Tags: exception, django-admin

I have the following models in `models.py`:

```
class ListinoTraduttore(models.Model):
        traduttore = models.ForeignKey('Traduttore', related_name='Traduttore')
        linguaDa = models.ForeignKey(Lingua, related_name = "linguaDa")
        linguaA = models.ForeignKey(Lingua, related_name = "linguaA")
        prezzoParola = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        prezzoRiga = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        scontoCat = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        scontoFuzzy = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        scontoRipetizioni = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = "Listini Traduttori"
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u"%s Da %s A %s Parola=%s Riga=%s ScontoCAT=%s ScontoFuzzy=%s ScontoRipetizioni=%s" % (self.traduttore, self.linguaDa, self.linguaA, self.prezzoParola, self.prezzoRiga, self.scontoCat, self.scontoFuzzy, self.scontoRipetizioni)


class Traduttore(models.Model):
        nome = models.CharField(nomeString, max_length=50)
        cognome = models.CharField(cognomeString, max_length=50)
        nomeAzienda = models.CharField(nomeAziendaString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        codiceFiscale = models.CharField(codiceFiscaleString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        partitaIva = models.CharField(partitaIvaString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        indirizzo = models.CharField(indirizzoString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        telefono = models.CharField(telefonoString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        fax = models.CharField(faxString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        referente = models.CharField(referenteString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        valuta = models.ForeignKey(Valuta)
        metodoPagamento = models.ForeignKey(MetodoPagamento)
        datiBancari = models.CharField(datiBancariString, max_length=50, blank=True)
        programmiUtilizzati = models.ManyToManyField(Programma, blank=True)
        note = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
        listino = models.ManyToManyField(ListinoTraduttore, related_name='listino', blank=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
                return u"%s %s %s" % (self.nome, self.cognome, self.nomeAzienda)
        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = "Traduttori"
```

While in the `admin.py` I have the following:

```
class TraduttoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ("nome", "cognome", "nomeAzienda")
        search_fields = ["nome", "cognome", "nomeAzienda"]

class ListinoTraduttoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ("traduttore", "linguaDa", "linguaA", "prezzoParola", "prezzoRiga", "scontoCat", "scontoFuzzy", "scontoRipetizioni")
        search_fields = ['traduttore__nome", "linguaDa", "linguaA"]
```

But when I try to make a search in the admin page in the `ListinoTraduttore` table I have the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/itrad/listinotraduttore/
Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/itrad/listinotraduttore/?q=Fenicio
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py in get_prep_lookup, line 142
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/nicolac/Documents/DjangoProjects/mysite',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 234):

This is to (hopefully) simplify the answer.

*Don't filter on a ForeignKey field itself!*

---

Change this

```
search_fields = ['foreignkeyfield']
```

to this (notice TWO underscores)

```
search_fields = ['foreignkeyfield__name']
```

`name` represents the field-name from the table that we have a ForeignKey relationship with.

Comment: It is the answer I want, BTW,  I tried: `search_fields = ['foreinkeyfield__foreinkeyfield__name']`, it works too. thanks

Answer (score 203):

Have you tried adding the `__fieldname` on those `Lingua` references in the `ListinoTraduttoreAdmin` search_fields, like:

```
class ListinoTraduttoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):        
    list_display = ("traduttore", "linguaDa", "linguaA", "prezzoParola", "prezzoRiga", "scontoCat", "scontoFuzzy", "scontoRipetizioni")
    search_fields = ['traduttore__nome", "linguaDa__field1", "linguaA_field2"]
```

Comment: it's just a really unhelpful error message.  This was basically the solution in my case.  for reference https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2331

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Fixed this issue when I did a search on any FOREIGN KEY. Thanks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as @seans mentioned, this error occurs every time there is a foreign key on the search_fields (django 1.11).

Comment: 6 years later that crappy error message is still there!

Comment: 8 years later, that message still kills us

Answer (score 83):

Use Django's double underscore convention instead. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)
`foreignkeyfield__name`

`Make sure you are not adding any Foreignkey or ManyToManyField to your search_field directly.`

```
class ListinoTraduttoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("traduttore", "linguaDa", "linguaA", "prezzoParola", "prezzoRiga", "scontoCat", "scontoFuzzy", "scontoRipetizioni")
    search_fields = ['traduttore__nome", "linguaDa__field1", "linguaA__field2"]
```

Comment: This was an important note! So if you want to search a ForeignKey, you should explicitely serch for the attributes there (e.g. my_related_object__first_attribute).

Answer (score 13):

Double underscore needed

```
class exampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 search_field = ('yourforeignkeyname__choosefieldnameinyourforeignkey')
```

Comment: Note: double underscore needed

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

Search the field of the foreign key using my_related_object__first_attribute:

```
search_fields = ('author__username', 'title')
from models
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,   related_name='blog_posts2')
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer the original question, but, every so often I run into a similar `invalid lookup` error because I accidentally used `_set` in a lookup, e.g. `<model_name>_set` instead of just `<model_name>`.

Basically, I tend to confuse the [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) with the [default_related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.default_related_name)
, which does include `_set` (also see [queries docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) and [related manager docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)).

From the [lookups documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

> It works backwards, too. Whilst it can be customized, by default you refer to a “reverse” relationship in a lookup using the **lowercase name of the model**.

(my emphasis)

Confusing thing is that the *default* `related_name` (i.e. `<model_name>_set`) is not the same as the *default* `related_query_name` (i.e. `<model_name>`), but if you set a *custom* `related_name` (or `default_related_name`, via model `Meta` options), that *will* also be used as the default `related_query_name` (as mentioned in the docs).

Comment: Thank you for leaving a trace of your findings. Helped me greatly today :-)

Answer (score 1):

This error, mostly occurs when you try to filter using a ForeignKey. I think the error is in the search_filelds. Check it. search_fields = ['traduttore__nome", "linguaDa", "linguaA"]. This two ForeignKey ("linguaDa", "linguaA") are the problem. Remove them. I think this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I stayed up all night looking for the solution and I found it at last.

This error occurs when you want to search a onetoonefield, foreignkey, or manytomanyfield.

The solution is:

```
search_feild = [<foreignkeyfeild>__<foreignkey name as it is in the main model>]
```

for example:

```
class FranchiseManager(AbstractBaseUser):

    BRANCH_MANAGER = "BR"
    EMPLOYEE = "EMP"

    DESIGNATION = [
        (BRANCH_MANAGER, "Branch manager"),
        (EMPLOYEE, "Employee")
    ]

    company = models.ForeignKey(MainManager, 
              on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
              first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, 
                          blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
    choices=DESIGNATION)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "first_name"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class ProductCategories(models.Model):
     manager = models.ForeignKey(FranchiseManager, 
               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.name} :-: {self.manager}"
```

Then search search will be as follows:

```
search_fields = ["manager__first_name"]
```

Comment: I found a mistake in your code. You have single quote at the beginning of and double at the end of the string   'traduttore__nome"

Answer (score 0):

it may be weird

```
search_fields = ['traduttore__nome']
```

giving like this , with single quotes will create error.

```
search_fields = ["traduttore__nome"]
```

giving with double quotes will fix the issue

```
foreignkeyfield__lookupfield  - this is the format
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the field either exists in the model or not, if not, then remove the search field from the search list.
Then, check if the search field value is either a foreign key or not, if any field is a foreign key, then please add the foreign key's field name like ForeignKey__FieldName (FieldName is the very field you wanna search).

Answer (score -3):

add in admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Traduttore, TraduttoreAdmin)
admin.site.register(ListinoTraduttore, ListinoTraduttoreAdmin)
```

see the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Hi, I did it but nothing change. I have the same error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This does not work. What we need to access is the foreign key field. which can be looked up as follows. ` [foreignfield__name]`