# Trouble passing foriegn key to form to filter for that key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-sessions

So the problem I keep hitting is the filter inside lesson_select form that would find all the lessons associated with it's respective textbook so that it can be returned as a list for the user to choose from. I'm pretty confused because I got the filter for grade working, but the filter by textbook has me stumped :S

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

```
class FooSelect(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Foos
        fields = ['foo_foo']
    
    def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super (FooSelect, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        foo_chosen = request.session['foo']
        self.fields['textbook_lesson'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FooS.objects.filter('foo.id' == foo_chosen))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.. the problem was with how I was trying to use access the foreign keys attributes. I needed to use 'code'foo__title = foo_chosen)'code' instead of the nonesense I was using in the question. I found my answer here: [Troubleshooting "Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754877/troubleshooting-related-field-has-invalid-lookup-icontains)